# jQuery and ajax gallery fade in and fade out effect on thumb clicks!

Tags: jquery, fade

Need some help, please.

I have a line of horizontal thumbnails loaded as ONE image with the different thumbnails images referenced via an imagemap as such:

```
<div id="zoom">
    <img src="" />
</div>
<div id="collectionindex">
    <img src="thumbnail-strip.jpg" alt="" usemap="#Map" />
        <map name="Map" id="Map">
            <area shape="rect" coords="151,0,211,39" href="image1.jpg" alt="" />
            <area shape="rect" coords="215,0,275,39" href="image2.jpg" alt="" />
            <area shape="rect" coords="279,0,339,39" href="image3.jpg" alt="" />
            <area shape="rect" coords="343,0,403,39" href="image4.jpg" alt="" />
            <area shape="rect" coords="407,1,467,40" href="image5.jpg" alt="" />
            <area shape="rect" coords="471,0,531,39" href="image6.jpg" alt="" />
        </map>
</div>
```

The IMG tag in the div with id="zoom" is my AJAX zoom window for when users "click" on the thumbnails to display the larger version of the image.

This is jQuery code I have to fadeIn the LARGE versions of the thumbnails in the ZOOM box.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("area").click(function(){

        var largePath = $(this).attr("href");

        $("#zoom img").attr({ src: largePath }).fadeIn("slow"); return false;
            });
    });
</script>
```

Right now, jQuery ONLY fades IN the first clicked on thumbnail, the rest simply just appear upon clicking, and not fade in. I'd like for it to work this way:

- user clicks thumbnail
- large image FADES IN to zoom box
- user clicks another thumbnail
- first image FADES OUT and second selected thumbnail FADES IN
- etc.

I hope I explained it clearly. :)  Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to fade the image out before changing the path & fading it in... so your click function should become:

**EDIT**: Forgot that the show/hide animations happened asynchronously, so you need to use a callback on the fade-out to trigger the rest... code should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("area").click(function () {
            var largePath = $(this).attr("href");
            $("#zoom img").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                $(this).attr({ src: largePath }).fadeIn("slow");
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for the quick response - just tried this and it except it looks like it DISPLAYS the newly selected LARGE image, FADES it OUT, then FADES it IN again.

i need it to:

FADE IN 1st image, after user selects it
when user selects next image
FADE OUT 1st image
FADE IN next image
etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new here and just saw my comment to your response was terribly styled.  :P

thank you for the quick response - just tried this and it except it looks like it DISPLAYS the newly selected LARGE image, FADES it OUT, then FADES it IN again.

i need it to:

- FADE IN 1st image after user selects
- user selects next image > FADE OUT 1st image > FADE IN next image
- and so on and so on.